# Exporting an Android Project based on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, export, google-play-services

i developed an android project using google-play-services_lib ( using google map ), my project is compiling and working fine as i want , but i want export my project in order to send it to someone else who should continue work on it , how can i include the google-play-services_lib's project in the same package.

PS :i have included the google-play-services_lib as lib

Answer (score 0):

Send the project and your remote partner has to install "Google Play Services" with the Android SDK Manager.

[image]

So, the library project of "Google Play Services" is included into the sdk, and is located in `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/` , he only need to import the project to his Workspace.

If you are using Eclipse, import the library project into your workspace. 
Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to import it.

**Update:**
or just copy the `google-play-services.jar` from google-play-services_lib/libs to the folder /libs of your project.
and delete the reference of google-play-services_lib of your project.

more info: [**Set Up Google Play Services SDK**](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i am looking for a way to package the whole projects in one , so the other partner doesn't have to import the library to the workspace.

Comment: have you tried copying the google-play-services.jar file into your project´s folder /lib?

Comment: yes i did , but then i have an error on my manifest file in this tag 
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />